# Web API OData v4 enum localization

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-web-api2, odata, odata-v4

I'm trying to use a Kendo grid with an OData v4 controller. Sending back a very simple LogEntry class that has a LogLevel enum on it, OData doesn't want to localize the name of the enum.

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public LogLevel Severity { get; set; }
}

public enum LogLevel
{
    [Display(Name = "Crazy Train Trace")]
    Trace = 0,

    [Display(Name = "Who Has Info?")]
    Info = 100,

    [Display(Name = "Lo and Behold: A Warning!")]
    Warning = 200,

    [Display(Name = "Exception")]
    Exception = 300,

    [Display(Name = "Uh oh, Jack...")]
    CriticalException = 400
}
```

This is my WebApiConfig.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();

    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<LogEntry>("LogEntry");
    builder.EnumType<LogLevel>();

    config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```

Is there any way to get OData to use some form of localization when it spits it out for the Kendo grid to display?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why this was down voted.  Did I ask it improperly?

Comment: Is it supposed to work? I mean is OData documented to understand Display attributes (on enum fields or else)?

Comment: @SimonMourier - I honestly don't know.  I don't think so.  Which to me, is a major issue/oversight? I'd be happy if there was ANY mechanism that would allow this to work.

Answer (score -1):

From a simple 5 minute search of the OData source code, you can easily see that there is no reason for you to expect that behaviour.

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/Formatter/Serialization/ODataEnumSerializer.cs

The solution is to extend the [ODataSerializationProvider](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/Formatter/Serialization/ODataSerializerProvider.cs) to return a custom ODataSerializer for when `type == typeof(LogEntry)`.

Then inject that new `ODataSerializationProvider` into the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`.

Comment: I have tried this, I simple doesn't work. Stuck with an error `CustomODataEnumSerializer does not support CreateODataValue.`